# Can't build application with boost.log

Tags: c++, boost

I get a link error when I include the boost/log header into source file.

> Error 5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class
>   boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl
>   boost::system::system_category(void)"
>   (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced
>   in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for
>   'native_ecat''(void)"
>   (??__Enative_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)    C:\Users\lukas\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\MyFilter\MyFilter\MyFilter.obj   MyFilter

So there seems to be the problem that i didn't link the system library. However i set the link library include path to include the boost library. 
The file is

> libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_55.lib

and is in D:\Program Files (x86)\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib - so that should work.

So why doesn't Visual Studio link it to the application? Or are there actually several boost system lib files It should have had compiled?

Comment: Did you add the path to _Additional Library Directories_? Are the libraries in the correct version? x86 to x86 project?

Comment: yes i did. I can actually build the application when I only use the trivial.hpp file of the log libraries. But the other ones don't work because they depend on the system libary

Comment: Also the versions are correct? What target are you using? Any CPU?

Comment: i run a 64 bit machine, but i am not actually sure if boost compiled to x64

Comment: Your machine ist not interesting, just boost and your project target should have the same version. Try to change the target to x86 and to x64. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx). Its equal to x86.

Comment: yes my project is x64

Comment: If the paths are correct, I really belive it is a version problem. To compile the different libraries use **(x86)** `b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage` ; **(x64)** `b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage`. I hope u get ahead.

Comment: I recompiled boost for 64bit mode and added boost_system-vc100-1_55.lib as additional dependencies and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like we discussed in the comments. Verify the version (x86 and x64) of the boost library and you're visual studio project, those version should be equal.

Here are the commands to compile boost:

x86:

```
b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage
```

x64:

```
b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage
```